# Get root directory razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I built html helper to change `class` attribute based on current page. When using MVC, I can get the value for Controller and Action by using this method

```cs
string actualAction = (string) html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
string actualController = (string) html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
```

Using `razor pages`, I can get the razor page endpoint by using this code

```cs
var rv = html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values;

string page = $"{rv["page"]}".ToLowerInvariant();
```

So I will get the value such like `/admin/dashboard`, `/admin/configuration/add-user`, `/admin/configuration/list-user` and etc.

At the endpoint, I want to know what is the first directory name. Following my example, the `admin` is a root directory.

Is there is a .Net core function handles this? or need to customize?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `HttpContext`. Check here on how to access it, depending where you are: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Then access the path from the context request:

```
Context.Request.Path
```

To use it from the view

```
@{
    var path = Context.Request.Path;
    ...
}
```